# What are examples of mathematical concepts named after the wrong people? (Stigler's law)

Tags: ho.history-overview, terminology, big-list

It's a common observation in Lie theory that Cartan matrices and the Killing form are named after the wrong people; they were discovered by Killing and Cartan, respectively.  I remember learning about many other examples of this phenomenon, but can't think of too many at the moment.  Wikipedia has some examples [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_examples_of_Stigler%27s_law) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_misnamed_theorems), but I'm curious about more obscure examples.

Bonus points for an interesting story behind why the concept was incorrectly named.  Concepts that were deliberately named in honor of another mathematician don't count.

Comment: By the way, in the mathematical community "Stiegler's law" is often referred to as "Arnol'd's law", inclusive of the corollary "Arnol'd's law applies to Arnol'd's law as well".

Comment: To further complicate things, there is also Whitehead's law: "Everything of importance has been said before by someone who did not discover it."

Comment: Oh gosh, I could not imagine that there are SO many wrong names. Perhaps some day there will be a big important Brandenburg theorem, of course just because another one has proven it. ;-)

Comment: Not that I have a problem with the question per se, but "the wrong people" is pretty ambiguous.  The first person to study something might not be the most deserving -- often a crucial application or popularizations trumps the actual innovation.  Nor is it necessarily the case that the intent of the naming was to honor the inventor -- frequently the naming is done for reasons of analogy ("Euler systems" come to mind).

Comment: According to Wikipedia' s article on Stigler's law, "Stigler attributes its discovery to sociologist Robert K. Merton"

Comment: Stigler's law is called Boyer's Law by H.C. Kennedy in "Who Discovered Boyer's Law?" (Amer. Math. Monthly vol. 79 1972, 66--67). It says that "Mathematical formulas and theorems are usually not named after their original discoverers." The label Boyer's law was chosen because Boyer gave many examples of this phenomenon in his book A History of Mathematics.

Comment: Very good historical notes,KC. 

Comment: The Arnold Principle. If a notion bears a personal name, then this name is not the name of the discoverer.
The Berry Principle. The Arnold Principle is applicable to itself.
http://pauli.uni-muenster.de/~munsteg/arnold.html

Comment: Here is another example. I'm quoting from page 204 of Arnie Miller's *Special subsets of the real line*, Chapter 5 of the **Handbook of set-theoretic topology**: "In 1914 Luzin constructed, using the continuum hypothesis, an uncountable set of reals having countable intersection with every meager set. The same construction had been published in 1913 by Mahlo. But (as is not unusual in mathematics) such a set has become universally known as a Luzin set."

Comment: Often, this French rule is at work: "On ne prête qu'aux riches."

Comment: If I had my druthers, all theorems would be named mnemonically for what they prove, and their actual histories would be stored in a readily accessible historical file.

Answer (score 28):

According to Wikipedia, Markov's inequality is due to Chebyshev, and Chebyshev's inequality is due to Bienaymé.

On top of that, Hölder's inequality was first proved by Rogers, and Jensen's inequality by Hölder. What a mess!

Comment: Related mess: Lipschitz and Hölder functions.

Comment: Would it be terminally geeky to point out that these attributions to Markov et al form a chain?

Answer (score 28):

Q: Who proved the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem?

A: Frobenius!

We now have the interesting question: Is this a maximal example of Stigler's law? That is, can we find distinct persons A, B, and C who are given credit for a result proven by D? Or A and B who are given credit for a result proven by C and D?

Comment: And how long a directed cycle can we find in the graph where there is an edge from P to Q if P discovered/proved something attributed to Q?

Comment: What do you mean? That Frobenius was the first to prove it in full generality? Please supply a reference, as Cayley and Hamilton at least had proofs in dimension 2 and 3, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Guys,I'm not sure,but I think Frobenius was the first to STATE the theorum in it's full generality,but he didn't succeed in giving a complete proof.That's why Arthur Cayley and Hamilton are given credit-they supplied the first general proof,improving on thier original proofs in low dimensions.I could be wrong about this,someone please chime in if you have the right answer and give a reference. 

Comment: I was told this by an older algebra professor of mine. Here's a reference (although I'm not sure how authoritative mathpages really is, especially because it doesn't cite sources itself): mathpages.com/home/kmath640/kmath640.htm

Comment: @Dave I almost have a example  for what you ask, if you accept it so. Cantor–Bernstein-Shroder theorem was according to wikipedia first proved by dedekind, althought he didn't published it.

Answer (score 24):

Stokes's theorem was stated by William Thomson (Lord Kelvin) in a letter to Stokes.  The letter is reproduced on the cover of Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds.  I believe the theorem was named after Stokes because he frequently put it on the Tripos exam in Cambridge.

Comment: According to wikipedia: Stokes set the theorem as a question on the 1854 Smith's Prize exam, which led to the result bearing his name.

Answer (score 23):

The [Pell equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation) was named so because Euler thought that John Pell was responsible for some key results involving this equation. While Pell was a notable mathematician, he had essentially no connection to the equation. The common belief is that Euler mistook Pell for Lord Brouncker who indeed had a number of results related to the "Pell" equation.

Comment: I thought some Indian mathematicians had something to do with it.  See André Weil's *Number Theory, from Hammurapi to Legendre*.

Comment: And doesn't a particular case go back to Archimedes (the cattle problem) ?

Comment: Indeed remarkable results on this equation have been obtained by Brahmagupta in the 7th century, and by Bhaskara in the 12th century.

Answer (score 22):

Zorn's lemma is neither due to Zorn, nor is it a lemma. It is a theorem due to Kuratowski.

Comment: Paul Campbell. The origin of Zorn’s lemma. Historia Mathematica, 5:77–89, 1978.

Comment: "Nor is it a lemma": this is a quite questionable and subjective assertion. As an intermediate statement which is not the ultimate goal and is used at many places in various contexts, I'm happy to view it as a (great!) lemma.

Comment: When a result is authored by just one -- it is a lemma, when by two -- it is a theorem.

Comment: According to Halmos, if I remember correctly, the ultimate accomplishement in mathematics is a lemma (and not a theorem) with your name.

Answer (score 21):

The most amazing example I know is the [Cayley formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_formula) which was discovered by Carl Borchardt nearly 30 years earlier.  Not only Cayley knew about this, in his paper he specifically wrote that this formula is due to Borchardt, and all he wants to do is give a new simple proof (without determinants as in the [matrix tree theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_tree_theorem)).

Answer (score 21):

The Frobenius automorphism associated to a prime ideal in a Galois extension of number fields was actually developed by Dedekind, who wrote about it (and the associated ramification groups, later found by Hilbert) in a letter to Frobenius on June 8, 1882.  Frobenius published this construction in a paper in 1896. Some citations:

1. Frobenius, Collected Works, Vol. 2, pp. 719--733.
2. van der Waerden, Modern Algebra, Vol. 1 (Spring 1966), p. 203.
3. Zassenhaus, Canadian Math. Bulletin 18 (1975), p. 448.

Answer (score 21):

Our linear algebra professor had a joke he told every year at the same spot in the lectures, for some 30 or 40 years. He'd say in an absolutely dry voice and facing the blackboard: "And this is the Cauchy–Bunyakovsky–Schwarz inequality, named like this because it was first proved by Lebesgue". Apparently, Cauchy just did it just as an inequality for sums (ie findim spaces), and Bunyakovsky and Schwarz independently as an inequality for integrals (ie for L2).

Comment: I wouldn't really call this "naming it after the wrong person". Lots of analytic facts come from natural generalizations of observations from finite dimensional vector space to $\ell_p$ spaces then to $L^p$ spaces.

Answer (score 21):

The Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein theorem was proved by [Dedekind](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/no_cache/dms/load/img/?IDDOC=46404); this link is to Dedekind's collected works and there is an informative note at the end.

Comment: Did Cantor even have anything at all to do with proving that?

Comment: According to Wikipedia, Cantor is the first to state the theorem as a theorem.  Presumably he had something that looked like a proof... as did Schroeder.

Answer (score 20):

Bézout's theorem

This result was discovered first by Newton in 1665. Even though MacLaurin (1720) and Leonhard Euler gave proofs, the theorem is usually attributed to Etienne Bézout who much later (1776) gave an incorrect proof of the result.

Comment: I'm not entirely convince of this--at least, that Newton, MacLaurin, and Euler all gave correct proofs.  Could you give a reference?

Comment: I did not say they all gave correct proofs. Apparently the general Bezout's theorem was not fully established until Halphen's proof (1873). 

According to Abhyankar's (on http://www.jstor.org/stable/2318338) Euler's argument from 1748 used a version of the resultant.

Comment: As far as I know (wikipedia agrees), this theorem was actually first proved by the French mathematician Bachet de Mézirac (1581-1638).

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, wrong Bezout's theorem...

Comment: Altough Bezout's formula (about gcd) is as I mentioned a good example of misattribution ! Bezout was a lucky guy, or a very good publicist.

Answer (score 18):

The number of plane trees with no vertex of degree one and with $n$ endpoints is known as a *Schröder number*, from a 1870 paper by Ernst Schröder. In 1994 David Hough discovered that these numbers were known to Hipparchus (*c*. 190 - after 127 B.C.)! For a popular account, see [https://math.mit.edu/~rstan/papers/hip.pdf](https://math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/papers/hip.pdf). For a more scholarly treatment, see http://stl.recherche.univ-lille3.fr/sitespersonnels/acerbi/acerbipub5.pdf ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20121030012247/http://stl.recherche.univ-lille3.fr/sitespersonnels/acerbi/acerbipub5.pdf)).

As an irrelevant aside, how do you make accent marks in MathOverflow? Schroder is supposed to have an umlaut over the o.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I've been curious about how Hipparchus could have come upon this since seeing a note to this effect in one of your books.

Comment: @Richard: I manually insert the accent marks using a compose key (which can be set to any key in the GNOME environment), i.e., for ö, hit compose " o

Comment: Huh. That we still don't know what might have been meant by "on the negative side" is pretty creepy.

Answer (score 15):

In my first algebra book the **Eisenstein criterion** for irreducibility of a polynomial is named **Schönemann criterion** and is left as an exercise. This is confusing when all others are talking about the Eisenstein criterion ;-).  In fact, here is a quote from Wikipedia:

> The criterion is named after Ferdinand Eisenstein. It was published by T. Schönemann in Crelle's Journal 32 (1846), p. 100, and was popularized by Eisenstein in Crelle's Journal 39 (1850), pp. 166-169. Eisenstein's application of this theorem was to polynomials with coefficients in Z[i], not Z.

Answer (score 14):

In reference to exactly this phenomenon (and in particular to the case of Pell's equation),  Andre Weil once observed that "This has happened many times in mathematics.  For example, I live on 'von Neumann Circle'.  **I** live there.  Yet still it is called 'von Neumann Circle' ".

Comment: Hmm, I don't like the above Andre Weil's joke.

Comment: @WlodAA, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24132/what-are-examples-of-mathematical-concepts-named-after-the-wrong-people-stigle#comment1115116_45251), it perhaps becomes more palatable if viewed as a joke *about* Weil.

Comment: @LSpice :  I interpreted it as Weil poking gentle fun at his own ego.  I am surprised that anyone took it otherwise.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg, nothing gentle about it.

Answer (score 12):

If you search for almost any eponymous topic in Wikipedia, you'll find that it was first studied by someone else. For example, the Gaussian distribution (according to Wikipedia) was first studied by de Moivre. It seems that in many cases, naming the body of work was given to the person who first applied its study to some other field (using the earlier example, Gauss used the distribution in astronomy).

The common story goes that L'Hôpital bought "the rights" to L'Hôpital's rule, as he was a nobleman and not a mathematician by trade, although I am not sure about the veracity of that story.

Although I am no expert on the history of Mathematics, it seems as though ideas or formulae assumed their names from certain mathematicians due either to a.) the more notable application or publication of the theory or b.) attribution by mathematicians of a later generation to pay tribute to (or garner attention from) the work of their predecessors.

Comment: L'Hopital hired Johann Bernoulli to teach him the calculus, and as allowed by their contract, wrote a book under his own name containing what he had learned, some of which were Bernoulli's original results.  Wikipedia has references.

Comment: Here is the Wikipedia page regarding the relationship between L'Hopital and Bernoulli: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Bernoulli#L.27H.C3.B4pital_controversy

Answer (score 12):

Currying should, I believe, be referred to as Schönfinkeling.

Answer (score 12):

An article in the current issue of *American Mathematical MONTHLY* (G. Folland, "A tale of topology," *Am. Math. Monthly* 117 (8) pp.663-672, Oct. 2010) quotes Walter Rudin as follows:

> Thus it appears that Čech proved the Tychonoff theorem, whereas Tychonoff found the Čech compactification -- a good illustration of the historical reliability of mathematical nomenclature.

Folland's article suggests the truth is more complicated, as it usually is.

Answer (score 11):

Chow varieties were invented by Van der Waerden (Chow was his student). And Hilbert schemes were invented by Grothendieck (who called them Hilbert schemes himself, however).

Answer (score 11):

Quoting from Alan Sokal's [2005 paper on the multivariate Tutte polynomial](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0503607):

"The [Potts model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potts_model) was invented in the early 1950s by Potts’ thesis advisor Domb. The $q = 2$ case, known as the [Ising model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model), was invented in 1920 by Ising’s thesis advisor Lenz. (I hasten to add that these are the only two cases I know of where the thesis advisor’s invention was named after the graduate student, rather than the other way around.)"

Answer (score 10):

The Banach-Steinhaus theorem was first proved by Hahn, the Hahn-Banach theorem was first proved by Helly.

Answer (score 9):

Burnside's Lemma, which asserts that the number of orbits of a group action is the average number of fixed points, was known to Cauchy.  Burnside himself even attributed it to Frobenius in his book.

Comment: I like the fact that this lemma is sometimes called "Burnside's Lemma" and sometimes "The lemma that is not Burnside's". 

Comment: This example appears in one of the Wikipedia entries mentioned above, though.

Answer (score 9):

The [Vandermonde Determinant/Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix). Apparently Vandermonde never explicitly discussed his eponymous determinant. According to Lebesgue in his survey of Vandermonde work, it was probably due to somebody misinterpreting Vandermonde's notation.

Answer (score 9):

There was a paper published in 2006 entitled "Simpson's Paradox in the Farey Sequence".  The paradox is not Simpson's nor is the sequence Farey's.  Bonus points.

Answer (score 9):

The Cayley numbers (also known as the Octonions) were discovered earlier by John T. Graves.  The story is nicely explained in John C. Baez's paper, *The Octonions*, Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 39 (2002), 145-205.

Answer (score 9):

Expanding on the example given in the original post, here's an excerpt from Borel's "Essays in the History of Lie Groups and Algebraic Groups" (p. 5):

> It has been remarked that, as far as terminology is concerned, posterity has not been kind to [Killing]: Cartan subalgebras, Weyl groups, fundamental reflections, roots, and the Coxeter transformation first appeared in his papers in some form. On the other hand, what now goes by his name, the "Killing form" seems to be a misnomer, and it may well be that I am the culprit. Cartan, Chevalley and Weyl never used this terminology. Once, J.J. Duistermaat and J.A.C. Kolk pointed out to me that, to their knowledge, its first occurence is in a paper of mine (Sém. Bourbaki, Exp. 33, May 1951). I do not remember why I chose it, though I probably felt I was innovating, since it is between quotation marks. It is rather likely that discussions with some members of Bourbaki had influenced me, but I cannot blame it directly on Bourbaki, since "Killing form" appears in Bourbaki drafts only from 1952 on. It is true that Killing was the first to remark that the coefficients of the characteristic equation (of a regular semisimple element), i.e. the elementary symmetric functions of the roots, are invariant under the adjoint group, but he did not make much use of the remark and did not single out the sum of the squares of the roots, of which Élie Cartan made such fundamental use in his thesis (1894). It would be more correct to speak of the Cartan form.

Answer (score 9):

[Jones' Conjecture](http://garden.irmacs.sfu.ca/?q=op/jones_conjecture).  Jones does not even exist; it's a Western pseudonym of Chuan-Min Lee.

Answer (score 9):

In honour of the recently departed Benoit Mandelbrot, perhaps it is appropriate to offer up the example of the Mandelbrot set, the first pictures of which were drawn in 1978 by Robert Brooks and Peter Matelski (according to Wikipedia).

Answer (score 8):

I was once told that Riemann's integral is due to Darboux, while Lebesgue integral is due to Borel. Riemann invented the Cauchy integral instead.

Comment: What is the "Cauchy integral"?  I tried searching for it, but I only get results about the Cauchy integral theorem or formula...

Comment: Say you want to integrate a fuction f on [0,1]. Then you define its integral, if it exists, as the limit of $\sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} f(i/n)/n$. Of course this does not make much sense unless f is continous. Still it is the most naif definition of integral one can come with and sometimes it works (and replacing the limit over n with the limit over the net of partitions of [0,1] almost gives you the right definition of Riemann's integral).

Comment: Are you sure that Darboux did not invent Darboux integral, and Riemann actually did invent Riemann integral? The definitions are different, although equivalent.

Comment: Well, I don't know Darboux integral, and sadly I don't remember the source where I read this, so I have no way to check.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_integral and 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral. So Darboux sums use only min and max on each interval $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$, whereas Riemann sums use $f(t_i)$ for some $t_i\in [x_i,x_{i+1}]$.



Comment: Part of the confusion might be that textbooks such as Rudin develop the theory of the Riemann integral by using the Darboux integral.  I also remember being told that Rudin goes on to assume that properties proven for the Darboux integral hold for the Riemann integral (and maybe even the Cauchy integral) without proving that this works.  Sneaky.

Comment: How about this:

A function is $Riemann{\ }integrable{\ }\iff$ the sup of lower $Darboux{\ }sums$ is equal to the inf of the upper Darboux sums $\iff$ it is bounded and the $Lebesgue{\ }measure$ of the set of discontinuity points is 0. 

Answer (score 8):

1. [Cauchy–Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) were known to d'Alembert and Euler.
2. Two-dimensional [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram)s were used by Descartes, three-dimensional - by Dirichlet. Also should be noted, that this construction has several other names in physics: Wigner–Seitz cells, Thiessen polygons.

Comment: I learnt about 1 from the treatise by A. Markushevic on Analytic Function Theory. In fact, in his books the denomination d'Alembert-Euler equations is the standard way to refer to them.

Comment: Very interesting!

Answer (score 8):

Banach algebras should probably be called Gelfand Algebras, or something similar.  I'm not sure of the history here, but presumably the "Banach" is attached because this is the study of "complete" normed algebras.  I don't believe that Banach actually did much work on algebras (as opposed to Banach spaces).

Comment: I can see your point, but I prefer the name Banach algebra, at least in part because it is easier to learn: it's just a Banach space with a continuous (bilinear, associative) multiplication.

Answer (score 8):

In logic:

- **Tarski's undefinability theorem** was obtained by Gödel before Tarski, who obtained it independently. Gödel did not publish the theorem. See Roman Murawski (1998), "Undefinability of truth. The problem of priority: Tarski vs Gödel", *History and Philosophy of Logic*, v. 19 n. 3. pp. 153-160
- The result sometimes known as **Gödel's diagonal lemma** was first stated by Carnap. Gödel (1934) explicitly attributed the result to Carnap (see Kurt Gödel, *Collected Works*, v. 1, p. 363).

Answer (score 6):

And the Bianchi identities are due to Ricci (according to Levi-Civita).

Answer (score 6):

To expand on Pasquale's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24132/what-are-examples-of-mathematical-concepts-named-after-the-wrong-people-stigle#comment50507_24132), here's a quote from Arnold's article [On teaching mathematics](https://web.archive.org/web/20170516211440/https://www.uni-muenster.de/Physik.TP/%7Emunsteg/arnold.html):

> Similarly to the fact that America does not carry Columbus's name, mathematical results are almost never called by the names of their discoverers.
>
> In order to avoid being misquoted, I have to note that my own achievements were for some unknown reason never expropriated in this way, although it always happened to both my teachers (Kolmogorov, Petrovskii, Pontryagin, Rokhlin) and my pupils. Prof. M. Berry once formulated the following two principles:
>
> *The Arnold Principle.* If a notion bears a personal name, then this name is not the name of the discoverer.
>
> *The Berry Principle.* The Arnold Principle is applicable to itself.

Perhaps somebody knows which results by Kolmogorov et. al. he is thinking of.

Comment: And since Columbus thought that he was in India, the original discoverers of America were named Indians. This is, I think, the feat of Europeans who are now called Americans.

Answer (score 6):

Nakayama's lemma was first proved by Krull in a special case, and by Goro Azumaya in the general case.

Comment: Did Nakayama at least "discover" the lemma? I think this is also important because I think no one complains about naming Fermat's last Theorem not after Wiles.

Comment: I think that's why many people prefer to call it NAK lemma.

Comment: It's not so clear. In the historical notes to his book, Nagata says that in the case N=0 and M an ideal, the lemma was given by Krull, and that the general case is in a paper of Azumaya. But Nagata learned it from Nakayama and Azumaya when he was an undergraduate. Since some mathematicians were calling it Nakayama's lemma, he asked Nakayama who had this formulation first, to which Nakayama responded that he did not remember whether Nakayama or Azumaya was the first. Probably it should be considered folklore, and the name "Nakayama's lemma" seems appropriate.

Comment: "History is a myth men agree to believe."-Napoleon Bonaparte 

Answer (score 6):

Pell's equation

By a mistake of Euler, the Diophantine equation y^2 - Ax^2 = 1 has been erroneously known as "Pell's equation"; but, in fact, the English mathematician John Pell (1611-1685) did no more than copy it down in his papers, from Fermat's letters of 1657 and 1658.

For an extensive historical account on "Pell's equation", see Sir Thomas L. Heath, Diophantus of Alexandria : A Study in the History of Greek Algebra (Dover Pub., New York, 1931-1963, 552 pages), Supplement, Section II: "Equation y^2 - Ax^2 = 1, pp. 277-292. Particularly in page 285, after a presentation of the history of the equation up to Fermat's time (including citations to Pythagoreans, Archimedes, Diaphanous, and the Indian solution), one can read that:

" ... Fermat rediscovered the problem and was the first to assert that the equation x^2 - Ay^2 = 1, where A is any integer not a square, always has an unlimited number of solutions in integers. His statement was made in a letter to Frénicle of February, 1657 (cf. Oeuvres de Fermat, II, pp.333-4). Fermat asks Frénicle for a general rule for finding, when any number not a square is given, squares which, when they are respectively multiplied by the given number and unity is added to the product, give squares. If, says Fermat, Frénicle cannot give a general rule, will he give the smallest value of y which will satisfy the equations 61y^2 + 1 = x^2 and 109y^2 + 1 = x^2 ? (Footnote 3: Fermat evidently chose these cases for their difficulty; the smallest values satisfying the first equation are y=226153980, x=1766319049, and the smallest values satisfying the second are y=15140424455100, x=158070671986249)." And, after a extensive quotation of Fermat's letter, in page 286, one can read that: "The challenge was taken up in England by William, Viscount Brouncker, first President of the Royal Society, and Wallis (Footnote 1: An excellent summary of the whole story is given in Wertheim's paper "Pierre Fermat's Streit mit John Wallis" in Abhandlungen zur Gesch. der Math., IX. Heft (Cantor-Festschrit), 1899, pp.557-576). See also H. Konen, Geschichte der Gleichung t^2-Du^2=1, Leipzig (S. Hirzel), 1901). At first, owing apparently to some misunderstanding, they thought that only rational, and not necessarily integral solutions were wanted, and found of course no difficulty in solving this easy problem. Fermat was, naturally, not satisfied with this solution, and Brouncker, attacking the problem again, finally succeeded in solving it. The method is set out in letters of Wallis (Footnote 2: Oeuvres de Fermat, III, pp.457-480, 490-503) of 17th December, 1657, and 30th January, 1658, and in chapter XCVIII of Wallis' Algebra; Euler also explains it fully in his Algebra (Footnote 3: Part II, chap. VII), wrongly attributing it to Pell (Footnote 4: This was the origin of the erroneous description of our equation as the "Pellian" equation. Hankel (in Zur Geschichte der Math. im Alterthum und Mittlelalter, p.203) supposed that the equation was so called because the solution was reproduced by Pell in an English translation (1668) by Thomas Brancker of Rahn's Algebra; but this is a misapprehension, as the so-called "Pellian" equation is not so much as mentioned in Pell's additions (Wertheim in Bibliotheca Mathematica, III, 1902, pp.124-6); Konen, pp.33-4 note). The attribution of the solution to Pell as a pure mistake of Euler's, probably due to a cursory reading by him of the second volume of Wallis' Opera where the solution of the equation ax^2 + 1 = y^2 is given as well as information as to Pell's work in indeterminate analysis. But Pell is not mentioned in connexion with the equation at all (Eneström in Bibliotheca Mathematica, III, 1902, p.206)."

For more information about "Pell's equation", see Harold M. Edwards, The Fermat's Last Theorem: A Genetic Introduction to Algebraic Number Theory (Springer-Verlag, New York, 1977, 410 pages), pp. 25-33. Particularly in page 33 one can read that

"This problem of Fermat is now known as "Pell's equation" as a result of a mistake on the part of Euler. In some way, perhaps from a confused recollection of Wallis's Algebra, Euler gained the mistaken impression that Wallis attributed the method of solving the problem not to Brouncker but to Pell, a contemporary of Wallis who is frequently mentioned in Wallis's works but who appears to have had nothing to do with the solution of Fermat's problem. Euler mentions this mistaken impression as early as 1730, when he was only 23 years old, and it is included in his definitive Introduction to Algebra written around 1770. Euler was the most widely read mathematical writer of his time, and the method from that time on has been associated with the name of Pell and the problem that it solved --- that of finding all integer solutions of y^2 - Ax^2 = 1 when A is a given number not a square --- has been known ever since as "Pell's equation", despite the fact that it was Fermat who first indicated the importance of the problem and despite the fact that Pell had nothing whatever to do with it."

See also André Weil, Number Theory : An approach through history - From Hammurapi to Legendre (Birkhäuser, Boston, 1984, xv+375 pages), in many different pages. In particular, at page 174, one can read that:

"Pell's name occurs frequently in Wallis's Algebra, but never in connection with the equation x^2 - Ny^2 = 1 to which his name, because of Euler's mistaken attribution, has remained attached; since its traditional designation as "Pell's equation" is unambiguous and convenient, we will go on using it, even though it is historically wrong."

Raul Nunes ( raul_nunes@uol.com.br )
NEST Nunes' Exposition of Scientific Truths
( http://www.geocities.com/raulnunes, [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20090728205758/http://geocities.com/raulnunes/) )

Comment: This example was mentioned by [@bhwang](https://mathoverflow.net/a/24164/2383).

Answer (score 5):

Euler's [nine point circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-point_circle) was [never discussed](https://web.archive.org/web/20080606002016/http://sunsite.utk.edu/math_archives/.http/hypermail/historia/jun00/0134.html) by Euler. This is an error of the "argument by authority" type: Catalan propagated that incorrect attribution made by another scholar, the "learned Terquem", without checking it himself.

Answer (score 5):

The "Lichnerowicz formula" relating the square of the Dirac operator to the Laplacian has been proved more than 30 years earlier by Schrödinger.

See: E. Schrödinger, *Dirac'sches Elektron im Schwerefeld*, Sitzungsber. Preuß. Akad. Wiss., Phys.-Math. Kl. 1932, 105-128 (1932).

Answer (score 5):

[Farey](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FareySequence.html) [fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence) were introduced by C. Haros. John Farey asked a question about them that reached Cauchy, and Cauchy then attributed the question and result to Farey, and the rest is history.

Answer (score 5):

Many of the examples mentioned go back to earlier centuries, when insulated national traditions and slow communications promoted mistaken labelling of results and concepts.   A much more recent example from the 1950s involves the notion of *Bruhat ordering* on a general Coxeter group, motivated at first by the example of finite crystallographic reflection groups in Lie theory.   The name seems to have been suggested by D.N. Verma in the late 1960s.  For some reason the ordering itself fails to appear (even in the exercises) in Bourbaki's influential 1968 Chapters IV-VI dealing with Coxeter groups, root systems, Weyl groups and affine Weyl groups.    Deodhar and others propagated the term "Bruhat ordering" in their papers, and as late as 1990 I routinely used this term in my book *Reflection Groups and Coxeter Groups*.   But by then Borel, who had gotten more deeply involved in sorting out the history of Lie theory, objected that the ordering was not at all found in Bruhat's development of the Bruhat decomposition but had occurred for Weyl groups in Chevalley's treatment of the partial ordering of closures of Bruhat cells (Schubert varieties) in the flag variety.

As a result many of us now try in principle to start with something like *Chevalley-Bruhat ordering* (shortened to Bruhat ordering) or even *Chevalley ordering*.   But this runs counter to a large body of literature including the 1979 Kazhdan-Lusztig paper.

Side remark: While Coxeter was the first to recognize the special presentation of a finite real reflection group that led to the term *Coxeter group* in Bourbaki, the general definition owes at least as much to people like Iwahori and Tits.   Coxeter was interested in traditional (often intricate) combinatorial geometry and not in Lie theory or its generalizations.   But short labels are easier to invent and tend to stick.

Comment: I don't think that insulated national traditions can be limited to earlier centuries. Aren't there many examples of differing attribution in the third quarter of the 20th century during the Cold War? 

Comment: @Carl: Certainly there have been artificial political barriers to communication and travel in more recent times, involving the Soviet Union, China, etc.   Even so, journal communication has been better than in earlier centuries.   Under Mao the Chinese universities often got pirated photocopies of western journals, for example, except during the Cultural Revolution.  Fortunately it's becoming harder for regimes to stifle email and internet use, though they keep finding new ways to try.     

Comment: What about Verma modules, then? My own recollection is that Harish-Chandra already used them in order to construct simple highest weight modules with dominant integral highest weights. On the other hand, Dixmier made a remark that Bernstein-Gelfands-Verma modules would have been a more justified name, although less practical.

Comment: @Victor: "Verma modules" are typical of many concepts which should be named after multiple people, but the name is not really wrong (just incomplete).  It's true that the modules played a technical role in the uniform existence proof for simple highest weight modules, but not until Verma's 1966 thesis were these modules studied seriously in their own right including the infinite dimensional ones.  The subtle error in Verma's false multiplicity 1 claim perhaps helped stimulate the further work of BGG, Jantzen, Kazhdan-Lusztig.   All of them soon made deep contributions to "Verma" modules.

Comment: Jim: Since you have mentioned Iwahori and Tits in connection with Coxeter groups, I am reminded of historical injustice in naming the $q$-deformation of the group algebra of $W$ the $\textit{Hecke}$ algebra (also by Bourbaki?), whereas it first appeared in the work of Iwahori and Matsumoto. George Lusztig has tried to correct this, but it may be too late now.

Comment: This gets more off-subject but is another example of fuzzy attribution.  It's due however to Iwahori's own modesty.  His important 1964 paper dealing with finite Weyl groups is titled "On the structure of a Hecke ring of a Chevalley group over a finite field".  This terminology propagates in his 1965 paper with Matsumoto dealing with affine Weyl groups and `$p$`-adic groups.  The 1979 paper by Kazhdan-Lusztig continues the use of "Hecke algebra" as does my 1990 book, but in my 2008 book on the BGG category I did mention the full label "Iwahori-Hecke" before reverting to the usual "Hecke".  

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps counterexamples to Stigler's/Arnol'ds law are actually the rare items.  The most significant one that I know is the Cartesian coordinate system which, strangely, seems to have actually been invented by Descartes!

Comment: Please note that Cartesius is the latin name under which Descartes was known.

Answer (score 5):

The Shimura-Taniyama conjecture was originally known as the Weil conjecture see http://www.ams.org/notices/199511/forum.pdf, also see the comment of Weil on page 7 (with other examples) in his response to Lang on the same issue as in the question posed here.

Additionally, the Frey curve was actually first considered by Yves Hellegouarch.

Comment: I think there is also some commentary on this situation in Shimura's _The Map of my Life_, which is quite an interesting read either way.

Answer (score 4):

The algebraic numbers that are now commonly called "*Gauss* sums" were studied in more general form than that introduced in Gauss's Disquisitiones by **Lagrange** [1].  In that same work, Lagrange shows how to generate an abelian extension of degree n by adjoining an nth root after, if necessary, adjoining the nth roots of unity.  These generators were later called "*Kummer* generators". *Jacobi* sums, which are closely related to Gauss sums, were studied earlier than Jacobi by **Gauss** and **Cauchy**.

Finally, a story best recounted by Weil [2]:  "For reference, we recall that the Gauss sums appear among the local constant factors in the functional equations of the $L$ functions;  these factors are also called "nombres radiciels" ("root-numbers", "Wurzelzahlen"), undoubtedly because of Hilbert, who a had a sort of genius for bad terminology, where it would have been sensible to name "Wurzelzahl" that which before him had been named a "Lagrange resolvent" , and "Lagrangian Wurzelzahl" that which here has been called a Gauss sum".

[1] Lagrange, Reflexions sur la resolution algebrique des equations, Nouveaux Mem. de l'Acad. R. des Sc. et B.-L. de Berlin, 1770-1771 = Oeuvres, vol. III, p. 332;

[2] Weil, La Cyclotomie Jadis et Naguere.

Answer (score 4):

Farey series, attributed to Farey, were actually first studied by Haros.

Comment: There is [another answer about Farey fractions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24132/what-are-examples-of-mathematical-concepts-named-after-the-wrong-people-stigle/24300#24300).

Answer (score 4):

A favorite of mine is l'Hôpital's rule. l'Hôpital paid Johann Bernoulli a retainer to keep him updated on developments in calculus and to solve problems he had. Correspondence shows that Bernoulli stated and proved the rule, which l'Hôpital then published.

Heine-Borel was first published by Borel, not Heine. In fact, Heine's name was attached because he was using similar methods to solve related problems. Too bad for both of them that it was actually Dirichlet who was the first recorded to have proved it, but his notes were published posthumously and after Borel's proof.

Cramer's Rule was published first by MacLaurin, and some believe MacLaurin knew the proof some 20 years before Cramer's publication.

Comment: On l'Hôpital, see [here](http://andrescaicedo.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/credit/).

Comment: This is the one I was looking for.   Our high school calculus teacher told us about it.

Answer (score 4):

**Tannakian categories**, a terminology chosen by N. Saavedra in his thesis under Grothendieck.

Grothendieck would prefer (Grothendieck–) Galois–Poincaré $\otimes$-categories.

See **Récoltes et Semailles**.

Comment: I recall that the name "tannakian" was, un fact, due to Grothendieck himself, but he didn't realise it until the end of Récoltes et Semailles. It's true that he preferred the other name you mention.

Answer (score 3):

[Pythagoras' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) apparently predates Pythagoras.

Comment: And similarly much of Euclid predates Euclid.

Comment: But so far as we know, Pythagoras (or one of his followers) was the first to prove it, or even to attempt to do so.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that Lagrange's theorem may well be one of the most prominent examples of the phenomenon under discussion.

According to **J. J. Rotman**,

> the theorem was inspired by work of
>   Lagrange (1770), but it was probably
>   first proved by Galois.

Curiously enough, the Wikipedia article adscribes the first complete proof of the theorem to Pietro Abbati Marescotti.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the Robin boundary condition was never studied by Robin. ([Gustafson, K. and T. Abe, (1998b). The third boundary condition – was it Robin's?, The Mathematical Intelligencer, 20, 63–71.)](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF03024402)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I've missed it, but it seems no one has mentioned Pascal's triangle. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle#History) it had a slew of earlier discoverers, going back to "The Persian mathematician Al-Karaji (953–1029) [who] wrote a now-lost book which contained the first formulation of the binomial coefficients and the first description of Pascal's triangle."

Wikipedia goes on to say, "The triangle was later named for Pascal by Pierre Raymond de Montmort (1708) who called it 'Table de M. Pascal pour les combinaisons' (French: Table of Mr. Pascal for combinations) and Abraham de Moivre (1730) who called it 'Triangulum Arithmeticum PASCALIANUM' (Latin: Pascal's Arithmetic Triangle), which became the basis of the modern Western name."

Answer (score 2):

Well Wigners rotation in special relativity which is the observation that two non-parallel boosts will result not in another boost but a composite of a boost and rotation was actually first formulated by Ludvik Silberstein in 1914, by Llewelyn Thomas in 1926 and then by Wigner in 1939, that is over two decades later.

Since Wigner acknowledged Silberstein's priority, I propose it be renamed Silberstein rotation ...

Answer (score 2):

$$
\sin x = \frac{2t}{1 + t^2}, \qquad \cos x = \frac{1 - t^2}{1 + t^2}, \qquad \text{and} \qquad dx = \frac{2}{1 + t^2}\,dt
$$
The **“Weierstrass substitution,”** used by Euler before Weierstrass was born and, according to Prof. Fred Rickey of the United States Military Academy, never mentioned in the writings of Weierstrass. After I referred to it by that name in a terse remark in the *Monthly*, Rickey sent me an email saying he had searched through Weierstrass's writings looking for it. I then sent an email to James Stewart, author of a wildly popular calculus textbook that does not differ from other calculus textbooks, asking whether he was the originator of the name. He replied that he was not, but I understand that some insist that he was.

Comment: I'm guessing the "Weierstrass substitution" is the one described in the Wikipedia article called ["Tangent half-angle substitution"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution).

Comment: @Amplitwist Correct. The name of that Wikipedia article has changed a few times, I think.

Answer (score 2):

The Gauss-Bonnet theorem can be proved using the Gauss
map, but the theorem itself appears to be due to Blaschke and the
original proof procedure is due to Rodrigues.

It seems that neither the theorem nor the proof of Rodrigues were known to Gauss or to Bonnet.

Comment: Is this the same Rodrigues who invented the so-called Hamilton quaternions, also?

Comment: I believe so, see for example https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11425-008-0029-8

Comment: Bonnet wrote ''Depuis que ce Mémoire est composé j’ai vu dans le tome III de la Correspondance de l’Ecole Polytechnique que M. Binet, dans une Note annexée a un Mémoire de M. Olinde Rodrigues, démonstrait de la méme manniére que moi le théorme de M. Gauss ··· .''

Comment: I am no longer sure about my claim that Gauss did not know the result, as he did prove it for a geodesic triangle (see  Gauss C F. Disquisitiones generales circa superficies curvas, 1827).

Answer (score 2):

Bell numbers, named after Eric Temple Bell who was **not** the first to study them.

\begin{align}
B_0 & = 1 \\
B_1 & = 1 \\
B_2 & = 2 \\
B_3 & = 5 \\
B_4 & = 15 \\
B_5 & = 52 \\
B_6 & = 203 \\
& \,\,\,\vdots
\end{align}

The Bell number $B_n$ is the number of partitions of a set of $n$ members.

It is also the $n$th moment of the Poisson distribution with expected value $1.$

In 1964 Gian-Carlo Rota wrote about these and called them exponential numbers.<sup>1</sup> At some time after that they came to be conventionally called Bell numbers.

In that paper Rota never mentions the connection with the Poisson distribution, although he did in later writings. He defines a linear functional $L$ on the space of polynomials in $u$ by saying $L((u)_n) = 1$ for all $n,$ where $(u)_n$ is the $n$th-degree falling factorial $u(u-1)(u-2)\cdots(u-n+1)$ and states a lemma:
$$
L(u p(u-1)) = L(p(u))
$$
for every polynomial $p(u).$ Those who have studied empirical Bayes methods in statistics will recognize that as a form of the Robbins lemma:
\begin{align}
& \text{If } X\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda) \\[6pt] & \text{then } \operatorname E(Xf(X-1)) = \lambda\operatorname E(f(X)).
\end{align}
(The function $f$ need not be a polynomial.)
This lemma was discovered by Herbert Robbins in the 1950s as a result of analyzing data on car insurance.

(1) Rota, Gian-Carlo (1964). "The number of partitions of a set". *American Mathematical Monthly.* 71 (5): 498–504.

doi:10.2307/2312585.

JSTOR 2312585.

MR 0161805.

Comment: So who was the first to study them?

Comment: @IraGessel : I don't know. Rota wrote "The earliest occurrence in print of these numbers has never been traced; as expected, the numbers have been attributed to Euler, but an explicit reference to Euler has not been given, and Bell doubts that it can be found in Euler's work." Rota mentions Eric Temple Bell and Jacques Touchard among those who have written about this sequence of numbers. The papers by Bell and Touchard that he cites are from the 1930s and the 1950s.

Comment: @IraGessel : Rota cites a paper of a person named Dobinski (and I think there's a diacritic missing from that spelling, although that is how Rota spelled it) that gives a formula that amounts to saying it's the expected value of the $n$th power of a Poisson-distributed random variable whose 1st power has expected value $1,$ but Rota doesn't mention the Poisson distribution. (But he did later.) Dobinski's paper appeared in 1877.

Comment: @IraGessel : Rota shows no sign of being aware of the Robbins lemma.

Answer (score 2):

[Wilson's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem)

According to Wikipedia:

> This theorem was stated by Ibn al-Haytham (c. 1000 AD) and in the 18th
> century, by John Wilson.    Edward Waring announced the theorem in
> 1770, although neither he nor his student Wilson could prove it.
> Lagrange gave the first proof in 1771.    There is evidence that
> Leibniz was also aware of the result a century earlier, but he never
> published it.

Answer (score 2):

Introduction of Gröbner basis and its algorithmic computation is due to Bruno Buchberger, but it is named after his advisor Wolfgang Gröbner.

Comment: It was my understanding that it was Buchberger himself who named them Gröbner bases. In that sense, this one does not seem like a misattributation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a real example, but it led to a nice gem in a recent abstract on the arXiv: "Glaisher's correspondence goes back to Euler."

(As far as I know Glaisher generalized Euler's bijection, which is why he gets the eponym -- in addition some people say "Euler-Glaisher" instead.)

Comment: Huh?  I don't follow.  Euler did not have "bijective proof" as a concept.  It was Glaisher who invented the bijection, but if I recall correctly never published it - Sylvester did it and attributed it to him some time later.  You are probably referring to Euler's "odd vs. distinct" partitions theorem.  Using modern "involution principle" technology one can convert analytic proofs into bijective, and in this case the one-line Euler's proof becomes Glaisher's bijection (this is O'Hara's theorem - see my survey on partitions and a recent paper on O'Hara algorithm, joint with Konvalinka). 

Answer (score 1):

I think the Kazhdan-Lusztig Conjectures are due to Vogan.

**EDIT.**

True or false, the claim is mainly based on the very first two paragraphs of

---

[II] Irreducible characters of semisimple Lie groups II. The Kazhdan-Lusztig conjectures. David A. Vogan, Jr. Duke Math. J. Volume 46, Number 4 (1979), 805-859. --- The link

[Link](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-46/issue-4/Irreducible-characters-of-semisimple-Lie-groups-II-The-Kazhdan-Lusztig/10.1215/S0012-7094-79-04642-8.short), [doi: 10.1215/S0012-7094-79-04642-8](https://doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-79-04642-8)

gives a universal access to the first page, which contains the two paragraphs in question. In case you don't have access to the full paper, here is a scan of the references (to completely understand the two paragraphs):

[image]

[image]

---

Here are two more references:

---

[I] Irreducible characters of semisimple Lie groups I, David A. Vogan, Jr., Duke Math. J. Volume 46, Number 1 (1979), 61-108.

[Link](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-46/issue-1/Irreducible-characters-of-semisimple-Lie-groups-I/10.1215/S0012-7094-79-04605-2.short), [doi: 10.1215/S0012-7094-79-04605-2](https://doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-79-04605-2)

---

[KL] David Kazhdan and George Lusztig, Representations of Coxeter groups and Hecke algebras, Inventiones Mathematicae, Volume 53, Number 2, 165-184.

[GDZ](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/en/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN356556735_0053&DMDID=dmdlog14), [eudml](https://eudml.org/doc/142660)

---

I would summarize things as follows.

Step 1. In [I] Vogan made a certain conjecture.

Step 2. [II] and [KL] were written simultaneously. Each paper cites the other. In [KL] Kazhdan and Lusztig also made a certain conjecture. When he learned this, Vogan immediately (or at least very fast) proved that the "Step 1 conjecture" implies that of Kazhdan and Lusztig. (He even showed that the "Step 1 conjecture" *generalizes* that of Kazhdan and Lusztig.)

But, again, the best is to read carefully the first two paragraphs of [II]. Vogan explains this much more clearly than I, and it's always better to hear things from the horse's mouth.

Comment: I never heard that! (Although the names of Goresky and MacPherson are sometimes mentioned). What is the source?

Comment: The answer is incorrect, since the KL 1979 paper (Invent. Math.) was the first to state the KL Conjecture based on Hecke algebras and KL polynomials.    Kazhdan and Lusztig were motivated by questions about singularities of Schubert varieties, Springer's representations of Weyl groups, Jantzen's work on Verma modules, etc.   Vogan was approaching similar machinery from the direction of real Lie group representations, which led him after the KL paper to complete parts of his own program using "KLV polynomials".  See Steven Kleiman's history of intersection homology (arXiv) for the role of GM.

Comment: Dear Victor, I've just discovered your comment! Usually I get an automated alert whenever somebody comments in one of my answers. I could almost swear I didn't get any for your comment. Next time, don't hesitate to email me! (My address is very easy to find, for instance on my MO page.) 

Comment: Dear Victor, dear Jim: Thank you very much for your comments. I'll try to explain how I view things in an edit (soon to come) to my answer, and you'll tell me why I'm wrong. In a nutshell, I'm referring to what Vogan did **before**, and not **after**, the *Inventiones* KL paper. Things are very clearly explained in the very first two paragraphs of http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.dmj/1077313724 Also I made this claim several times in presence of David Vogan, and he never objected. (I'm sure you know his honesty and modesty.) 

Comment: I think this is mostly a labelling question, since what most people have referred to over the years as *the Kazhdan-Lusztig Conjecture* (soon proved geometrically by Beilinson-Bernstein, Brylinski-Kashiwara) concerns multiplicities in Verma modules.   What Vogan developed was in a sense "equivalent" but not the same statement in spite of his modest label.   The KL formulation has had natural analogues in other kinds of representation theory.  And Jantzen's older conjecture on Verma module filtrations was later seen to *imply* it, but the formulations are quite different.

Comment: Here is what I believe. What people call the "KL Conjecture" is Conj. 1.5 of [KL] (the *Invent.* paper). In [II] (the 2nd Duke "Irred. Char." paper of Vogan), this conjecture is stated as Conj. 3.3; the conjecture of [I] (the 1st "Irred. Char." paper) is labeled Conjecture 2.5; and it is proved (Theorem 3.5) that Conj. 2.5 implies Conj. 1.5 of [KL]. Thanks for correcting me if I'm wrong.

Comment: As Jim has said, there are several related conjectures here, with Jantzen's conjecture the strongest in the complex group case ($\iff$ the Verma module case) and Vogan's conjecture the most general (real reductive group); however, "Kazhdan-Lusztig conjecture" unambiguously refers to the statement that $[M_w:L_y]=P_{w_0y,w_0w}(1),$ and KL were the first to relate the multiplicities to Hecke algebra, although Joseph had been working in that direction and Goresky and MacPherson's work on intersection cohomology served as a motivation for defining KL polynomials. PS: CW --> no notification?

Comment: Dear Victor. Thanks again. I feel we all agree that 
"Kazhdan-Lusztig conjecture" is Conjecture 1.5 of the 
*Inventiones* paper [KL] (I'm designated the papers as 
in the answer). I think we also agree that, when KL were 
writing [KL], they knew that Conj. 3.15 of [I] implied 
their Conj. 1.5. [There is, in this story, a lot of math 
I don't understand. I'm just trying to make a very 
limited factual point.]

Comment: The link http://www.iecn.u-nancy.fr/~gaillard/vogan_ref.pdf seems to be dead - and I found it neither [on the new site](https://sites.google.com/site/pierreyvesgaillard) nor [in the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.iecn.u-nancy.fr/~gaillard/vogan_ref.pdf). (But since the bibliographic data and the link to the journal version are given, this probably doesn't really matter.)

Answer (score 1):

Morse theory is named after Marston Morse; it was widely used at least 50 years earlier. Wikipedia mentions Cayley and Maxwell, in the context of topography. Maxwell also used it in his work on electromagnetism, as detailed (complete with extensive passages from Maxwell's treatise) in the appendix of *Mystery of point charges* (A. Gabrielov, D. Novikov and B. Shapiro)
[available here (subscription)](https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/pdm012)

Comment: I'm not sure this is a fair example.The generalized theory of critical points in Euclidean space was used to be sure far earlier then Morse-but Morse and his contemporaries made the vital step of generalization to the topological language of manifolds. I'm not sure we should call what Maxwell and the others used strictly speaking Morse theory,but it's direct ancestor in Euclidean space. 

Comment: @Andrew L: At the same time, it appears unfair to penalize Maxwell when the topological setting in question was not available at the time. Maxwell probably did all he could do within the limited framework of his era, and while I readily acknowledge and appreciate Morse's contribution, Maxwell hardly gets any credit at all for what he did achieve.

Comment: @Thierry Maxwell and the others certainly deserve credit for making critical progress in Morse Theory's development,but we clearly can't call what they were doing Morse theory by modern standards,any more then we can call the work of Issac Barrow calculus since he didn't recognize the connection between the quadrature (integration) problem and the tangent (derivative) problem. Of course,that does nothing to invalidate the historical importance of Barrow's work with limits,which was the stepping stone to Newton and Lebnitz's breakthroughs.

Comment: What's the history of the Morse Lemma?

Answer (score 1):

Some people have tried to give examples with as high a multiplicity as possible. I want to try to break the record for the smallest non-zero example: Martin's axiom was introduced by Martin and Solovay. (I judge that to have multiplicity 1/2.)

Comment: Sorry, but this is a non-example. Martin's axiom was introduced by Martin. It is true that this happened in a paper by Martin and Solovay, and that it was after a construction of Solovay and Tennenbaum suggested it, but there is no misnomer here. 

Comment: So much for trying to find examples on Wikipedia. But perhaps that actually improves my example, making its multiplicity even smaller than 1/2.

Answer (score 1):

Liouville talked about the Legendre function when he studied the so-called Euler Gamma function. It made me doubt about who defined the Gamma function first.

Answer (score 1):

I had a companion observation that almost noone attributes the well-known sum-of-roots, product-of-roots etc. polynomial formulas as [Vieta's formulas](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VietasFormulas.html) as I [posted on Yahoo!Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080801032745AAzQ8WH) ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20210413213716/https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080801032745AAzQ8WH)).

Because as user absird pointed out, it makes that sort of topic Google-proof;
at least a bad name is better than no name for purposes of searching or discussion.

> ('Yes it's very hard to refer to
> something when noone knows it by its
> proper name or uses that name. I tried
> many Google searches on "sum-of-roots
> product-of-roots" and it was almost
> impossible to get a coherent lead.')

MathWorld notes: The theorem was proved by Viète (also known as Vieta, 1579) for positive roots only, and the general theorem was proved by Girard.

Comment: Really?  People in high school competition circles, at least in the US, are generally pretty good about calling them Vieta's formulas.  

Comment: It may be geographically dependent.

At high school level, no.
I was educated in Ireland and never saw these referred to as Vieta's formulas.
Even in college they would be blankly presented as 'properties of polynomials'. If you google (and manage to find them as 'sum-of-roots') that is typically how you will find them presented.

At IMO level, perhaps. Even then I don't recall ever seeing the name (not like Cauchy-Schwarz, Hölder, Pappus, Chinese Remainder Theorem et al).
Personally I only found out the name in 2008, i.e. 20 years later.
And it's not like I didn't read a lot.

Comment: I was educated in the US, and was unaware of the name "Vieta's formulas" until about two minutes ago.

Comment: @Charles: Uhuh. What name, or topic, were they taught to you under? ('properties of polynomials'?)

Comment: Thanks @MartinSleziak for adding the WaybackMachine link

Answer (score 1):

According to [this link](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Steiner_system) **Steiner Systems** were mentioned by by W Woolhouse in 1844 before the famous Kirkman Schoolgirl problem (P Kirkman 1847) - Steiner's work was more systematic and did advance the theory, but it came in 1853.

Answer (score 1):

[Marden’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marden%27s_theorem) was proved by Siebeck.

What rankles is that Marden himself cited Siebeck but it is now called Marden’s theorem. Dan Kalman was the one who brought this to people's attention and his defense is

> I call this Marden’s Theorem because I first read it in M. Marden’s wonderful book.

Answer (score 1):

De Bruijn sequences are so named because Nicolaas Govert de Bruijn enumerated them in 1946, but he later [acknowledged the priority of C. Flye Sainte-Marie](https://web.archive.org/web/20110716064847/http://alexandria.tue.nl/repository/books/252901.pdf), who enumerated them already in 1894.

Answer (score 0):

*Cayley numbers*, best known nowadays as the octonions, were first discovered by John Graves in 1843 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion).

Comment: Aargh — despite attempting to scan the previous answers before posting, I missed this one.

Answer (score -1):

Cartan discovered the Killing form, and Killing discovered the Cartan matrix.

Comment: That's the example I used in the original post :)

Comment: Aw, nuts, that's what I get for not reading things carefully. :)

Answer (score -1):

The notion of Frobenius manifold is due to Dubrovin

Comment: Why -2 votes???

Comment: This seems to be a concept that was deliberately named in honor of Frobenius, and as such, was explicitly excluded by the OP.